# Caffe Compilation Error: gflags.cc' is being linked both statically and dynamically into this executable

Tags: c++, makefile, deep-learning, caffe, gflags

I am trying to install caffe following this [tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation)

Basically I have the following error when I type the last make command:

```
me@dl-01:/home/me/caffe-master$ make runtest

.build_release/tools/caffe

caffe: command line brew

usage: caffe command args

commands:

train           train or finetune a model

test            score a model

device_query    show GPU diagnostic information

time            benchmark model execution time

Flags from tools/caffe.cpp:
 -gpu (Run in GPU mode on given device ID.) type: int32 default: -1
 -iterations (The number of iterations to run.) type: int32 default: 50
 -model (The model definition protocol buffer text file..) type: string
      default: ""
 -snapshot (Optional; the snapshot solver state to resume training.)
 type: string default: ""
 -solver (The solver definition protocol buffer text file.) type: string
 default: ""
 -weights (Optional; the pretrained weights to initialize finetuning. Cannot
      be set simultaneously with snapshot.) type: string default: ""
.build_release/test/test_all.testbin 0 --gtest_shuffle 
ERROR: something wrong with flag 'flagfile' in file '/root/glog-0.3.3/gflags-master/src/gflags.cc'.  One possibility: file '/root/glog-0.3.3/gflags-master/src/gflags.cc' is being linked both statically and dynamically into this executable.
make: *** [runtest] Error 1
```

I don't understand how to solve this error. Did anybody find this error before? how can I solve it?

Answer (score 11):

Whether or not you've already solved this somewhere else, I'm posting the answer here in-case others run into the same problem.

Primarily, this problem seems to have come about because **we don't always read things properly** and blindly follow all instructions thinking they all apply to our case. *hint: **they don't.***

In the installation instructions for Caffe (presuming Ubuntu instructions), there is a section which states:

> **Everything is packaged in 14.04.**
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev protobuf-compiler
> ```

Blindly ignoring the next title, which states clearly:

> **Remaining dependencies, 12.04**

we go on to install these dependencies, building and installing as required, resulting in the unfortunate side-effect of having 2 versions of libgflags, one dynamic (in `/usr/lib[/x86_x64]` and one static in `/usr/local/lib`

**Resolution**

1. Promise ourselves failthfully we'll read instructions properly next time around.
2. Uninstall libgflags

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove -y libgflags
   ```
3. Delete `make install` versions

   ```
   sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/libgflags.a /usr/local/lib/libgflags_nothreads.a
   sudo rm -rf  /usr/local/include/gflags
   ```
4. Clean Caffe build

   ```
   cd <path>/<to>/caffe
   make clean
   ```
5. Re-install libgflags package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y libgflags-dev
   ```
6. Rebuild Caffe

   ```
   make all
   make test
   make runtest
   ```

Et Voila. All tests should now run and you're ready to rock the deep-learning boat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, but in my case only performing step 3&4 solved the problem. Step-1 is of course for the next time :-D Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.
it saves my time :)

Comment: I followed ur steps but ended with the following error: `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.a(gflags.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.a: error adding symbols: Bad value`

Answer (score 4):

I've worked out a way to debug this issue analytically.  In my case, I was cross-compiling for an older ABI, so apt-get wasn't an option and I was compiling all dependencies manually.

First let's take a look at what this issue actually is.  In the Google GFlags library, flags are declared through global objects.  When the global object's constructor is run, it calls into the GFlags library to register that command line flag.  If the global constructor gets run multiple times (due to multiple versions of the library containing it being loaded into memory), then the GFlags register method dies with an error.

What does GLog have to do with this?  Well, GLog uses GFlags, and it has globally declared flag objects.  Even if GFlags is linked correctly, if the GLog library gets loaded multiple times, you get an error pointing to logging.cc in GLog.

Sounds like quite a mess, huh.  Even if GLog and GFlags are linked as shared in most cases, if another library links to a static version or some other version, kaboom.

Luckily, we can debug this issue using GDB and other tools, if you're willing to delve through some tricky symbol analysis.
First, you'll want to run GDB on the Python interpreter when it tries to import caffe:

```
gdb --args python -c 'import caffe'
```

Now, run the program once through so that GDB can pick up all the libraries it imports:

```
(gdb) r
```

Now, we can set a breakpoint on the place in the function (`FlagRegistry::RegisterFlag()`) that prints the error message, and run it again.  Note that this line number is from my version of GFlags (2.2.2), you may have to look at the source code of your GFlags version and get the line number.

```
(gdb) break gflags.c:728
(gdb) r
```

Hopefully, GDB should then break on the first instance of the error (if not, check that gflags has been built with debugging symbols).
Look at the backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  google::(anonymous namespace)::FlagRegistry::RegisterFlag (this=0xa33b30, flag=0x1249d20) at dev/gflags-2.2.2/src/gflags.cc:728
#1  0x00007ffff0f3247a in _GLOBAL__sub_I_logging.cc () from prefix/lib/libcaffe2.so
#2  0x00007ffff7de76ca in call_init (l=<optimized out>, argc=argc@entry=3, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffdb08, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffdb28) at dl-init.c:72
#3  0x00007ffff7de77db in call_init (env=0x7fffffffdb28, argv=0x7fffffffdb08, argc=3, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:30
#4  _dl_init (main_map=main_map@entry=0xd9c2a0, argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdb08, env=0x7fffffffdb28) at dl-init.c:120
#5  0x00007ffff7dec8f2 in dl_open_worker (a=a@entry=0x7fffffffcf70) at dl-open.c:575
#6  0x00007ffff7de7574 in _dl_catch_error (objname=objname@entry=0x7fffffffcf60, errstring=errstring@entry=0x7fffffffcf68, mallocedp=mallocedp@entry=0x7fffffffcf5f, 
    operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff7dec4e0 <dl_open_worker>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffcf70) at dl-error.c:187
#7  0x00007ffff7debdb9 in _dl_open (file=0x9aee70 "prefix/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe2/python/caffe2_pybind11_state.so", mode=-2147483646, 
    caller_dlopen=0x51bb39 <_PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc+233>, nsid=-2, argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, env=0x7fffffffdb28) at dl-open.c:660
#8  0x00007ffff75ecf09 in dlopen_doit (a=a@entry=0x7fffffffd1a0) at dlopen.c:66
#9  0x00007ffff7de7574 in _dl_catch_error (objname=0xabf9f0, errstring=0xabf9f8, mallocedp=0xabf9e8, operate=0x7ffff75eceb0 <dlopen_doit>, args=0x7fffffffd1a0) at dl-error.c:187
#10 0x00007ffff75ed571 in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff75eceb0 <dlopen_doit>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffd1a0) at dlerror.c:163
#11 0x00007ffff75ecfa1 in __dlopen (file=<optimized out>, mode=<optimized out>) at dlopen.c:87
#12 0x000000000051bb39 in _PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc ()
<snip>
```

Well that's a lot to deal with, but let's focus on the line that's actually important:

```
#1  0x00007ffff0f3247a in _GLOBAL__sub_I_logging.cc () from prefix/lib/libcaffe2.so
```

This is the call to the constructor for the global variables in logging.cc (which is part of GLog).  As you can see, this call is in libcaffe2.so, meaning that GLog has been statically linked to libcaffe2.so [I was using caffe2, but this procedure should be the same for both].

You can then set a breakpoint on `google::(anonymous namespace)::FlagRegistry::RegisterFlag` and rerun the program from the start.  Look at each call to RegisterFlag(), and figure out where this particular flag was registered the first time.  If the library providing the flag is a shared library, then it should only ever get registered from that .so file, and nowhere else.

To confirm the diagnosis, you can use

```
nm <library> | grep _GLOBAL__sub_I_logging.cc
```

to check for that init function in a library file.  Once you've found your culprit, you'll need to rebuild it so that it doesn't link to GFlags/GLog statically.

Answer (score 1):

I also had two libraries installed, a shared .so library and a static .a library. I removed them all as well as the /usr/local/include/glog folder.
The .so file I had brought over when I (cross) compiled the system, while the .a was from a native and up-to-date build.
Ultimately it came down to building glog (natively) in such a way that it provided the .so files.
I started with a clean download:

`git clone git://github.com/google/glog`

Then I edited CMakeLists.txt.
Where it says:

```
add_library (glog
  ${GLOG_SRCS}
)
```

I changed it to:

```
add_library (glog SHARED
  ${GLOG_SRCS}
)
```

Next you should be able to follow the other instructions. For my particular case I had to use slightly different instructions, not saying you have to do this. For me it was:
mkdir build
cd build

```
export CXXFLAGS="-fPIC"
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

This gave me the .so files and put them in the right place. Then I started over with caffe and it fixed the error for me.

Comment: I get this error Linking CXX shared library libglog.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgflags.a(gflags.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC